# Play a video file from the LAN

Tags: android, video, lan

I have a server and some android devices, all connected to the same wifi. How can I play a video file from the server, without accessing the internet?
I tried using VideoView, but I could load only urls so I used ngrok, but then it goes to the internet...

Answer (score 0):

If it is a statically hosted video on a local server on the LAN, and you have the URL that accesses the video, then you should be able to simply enter the URL into a browser on your client machines.

You do need to make sure the video is one that is supported on the machine and by the browser - testing with some commonly available videos would be a good start. The traditional 'Big Buck Bunny' video here in mp4 format is a good one to download to test with:

- http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html

if you look at the source of that page for example you will see the direct URL for the mp4 video which you can test in a browser directly you want.

The same should work on your local network if you server can server static video files. Note that is worth checking your sever supports range requests also - this allows the file be requested chunk by chunk, so playback can start as soon as possible, rather than having to wait for the whole file to download. Most servers do support this although you may have to enable it in the configuration.

**Serving static video files on a web server**

Video files can be viewed as just web resources, in the same way a document, image of file might be. Note that this is not the most efficient way to serve video over the internet, which is why there are specialised streaming servers, but it will work if you just need a simple solution.

Difefrent web servers have different approaches to serving static content, so you need to check with the server you are using, but as an example with a node.js server the follow code will serve any video files that are simply placed in the 'videos' directory:

```js
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var morgan = require('morgan');

//Define the app
var app = express();

// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log', {flags: 'a'});

// setup the logger
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));

// Constants
var PORT = 3000;

//Use static middleware to serve static content - using absolute paths here (you may want something different)
app.use('/videos', express.static('/videos'));

//Add error handling
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log("error!!!");
    console.log(err.stack);
});

// Video Server test page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("In Get!!!");
    res.send('Hello world from Video server\n');
});

//Start web server
var server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

The URL for the video will be: http://[your server url]/videos/[name of your video file]

Comment: Can you comment and explain the down vote - is there something incorrect that can be corrected?

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted, but it's just not answering the question.. The question was how to make the files static and have a url to access them.